# How to create parameterized Ext Rest Proxy on my Ext Store

Tags: javascript, rest, extjs, single-page-application, sencha-architect

I have a API that sends out a paginated result of data and I want it to be consumed my Ext JS app but I don't know how to supply the needed parameters.

Here is the response I expect:

```
{
  "currentPage": 1,
  "from": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "customer": "Customer 1",
      "movie": "Movie 1",
      "dateRented": "2021-01-25T01:22:42.143",
      "dateReturned": "2021-01-25T01:22:50.447"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "customer": "Customer 2",
      "movie": "Movie 2",
      "dateRented": "2021-01-25T01:22:42.15",
      "dateReturned": "2021-01-25T01:22:54.573"
    }
  ],
  "pageSize": 2,
  "to": 2,
  "totalCount": 1000003,
  "totalPages": 500002,
  "hasPreviousPage": false,
  "hasNextPage": true
}
```

Here is the endpoint:

```
/api/Rentals/{currentPage}/{pageSize}
```

Here is my Ext store but I don't know how I will be able to pass the value for currentPage and pageSize:

```
Ext.define('Vidly.store.PagedRentals', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.pagedrentals',
    storeId: 'pagedrentals',
    model: 'Vidly.model.PagedRental',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'https://localhost:44313/api/Rentals/',
        useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' },
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true
        }
    },
});
```

And here is the model:

```
Ext.define('Vidly.model.PagedRental', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'currentPage', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'from', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'to', type: 'int' }, 
        { name: 'pageSize', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'totalCount', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'totalPages', type: 'int' },
        ],
    hasMany: 'Rental',
});
```

I hope someone can help me with my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the beforeLoad method and change the url accordingly.

Comment: Where do I put the beforeload method? And it is it possible to update the parameters on the fly? Ex: next page, previous page or changing pageSize?

Comment: It is possible to do with buildUrl method. Your model is a little bit strange, it must contain the id, customer, dateRented, returnDate fields.. and your store must have rootProperty: 'items'.. Have you checked your code?

Comment: You could add a listener on the store -> listeners -> beforeload. Inside the the callback you can do something like (store is the first param of that fn) -> store.getProxy().getExtraParams() -> modify -> set and load. But as Arthur and Zoltan mentioned, i would suggest to improve the backend response structure (model) (if possible) as well as use query instead of pathparameters. This will make your life much easier.

Comment: Actually I am trying to learn ExtJS for multiple scenarios. Yes changing the API would fix my problem but what if I encountered a scenario that I don't have control over the API. These are the things that I am preparing to.

Comment: @hwsw cam you show me a snippet on how I can do the url change on the store beforeload? That would help a lot thanks.

Comment: @ArthurRubens the purpose of the model is to give the UI the numbers of data so that it can be binded on the UI side. If you have a better suggestion on how to structure the model I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext's rest proxy is designed to use standard REST APIs where paging and filtering options are passed in as query parameters. I.e. something like

`https://localhost:44313/api/Rentals?start=1&limit=25`

I would recommend to use this approach rather than a non standard REST API. It will enable you to use Ext's related features seamlessly.

If there is no way to change the API and you need to stick with your current server configuration then you need to create a custom proxy overriding some of the related functions. The best bet if you override the buildUrl function and pass your custom generated URL to the request object.

**UPDATE**

You can start with this code (also created a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3bmh)):

```js
Ext.define('Yournamespace.proxy.custom', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',
        alias: 'proxy.custom',
        buildUrl: function(request) {
            const url = this.callParent([request]);
            const operation = request.getOperation();
            console.log(url, this.getParams(operation))
            return url;
        }
    });
    
 Ext.define('User', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
 });

 
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    launch : function() {
    var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
         model: 'User',
         pageSize: 10,
         proxy: {
             type: 'custom',
             url: 'https://localhost:44313/api/Rentals/',
             reader: {
                 type: 'json',
                 rootProperty: 'users'
             }
         },
         autoLoad: true
     });
    }
});
```

You can write your custom code to the `buildUrl` function. Currently only the default URL and the params are collected and logged there but it does the default stuff. You can tweak the URL here and return the new URL at the end.

Comment: Can you show or teach me how I could do a custom proxy for overriding and how I can call it from the view controller when changing pages. I am still a beginner on ExtJS so a snippet would greatly help. Thank you.

Comment: I assume it means there is no way to change the API to use proper REST parameters :). I will update my answer as soon as time permits.

Comment: Added an example for you to overwrite the buildUrl function. Enjoy. :)

Comment: I completely agree with using standard REST API. Can you tell me how to change the page with this URL: https://localhost:44313/api/Rentals?start=1&limit=25 from a grid?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Please provide more details.

Comment: I will just post a new question for this. Thanks.